How to move with arms position held?
I have set angles for joints in the arm, and want to make NAO walk few centimeters, but as soon as the robot starting walking the arms moves from the initial position. I do it as follows by setting stiffness of the arms to 1.0 after they are set to their target positions:
self.motion.wakeUp()
self.set_stiffness(['RArm', 'LArm'], 1.0)
self.motion.moveTo(0.3, 0.0, 0.0)

what is missing here to make the arms position unchanged while make NAO walks 0.3 meters?

You could deactivate the arms' motion relative to walk by using the ALMotion proxy's method setWalkArmsEnabled(False,False).
cf http://doc.aldebaran.com/1-14/naoqi/motion/control-walk-api.html#ALMotionProxy::setWalkArmsEnabled__bCR.bCR
(or from other version depending of the robot you use)
Good luck!
